# GetOpenFileName Multiselect:= True error when cancel is clicked

Tags: vba, excel

I get an error of type mismatch whenever the cancel/quit button in the dialogue box is clicked.

The error appears on `Application.GetOpenFileName`.

```vb
Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long, j As Long, iCheck As Long
Dim fname() As Variant

Dim wkbNameList As String, wkbNamePath As String
Dim win As Window

fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel, *xlsx; *xlsm", MultiSelect:=True)

If fname = "False" Then
   Exit Sub
End If

For i = LBound(fname) To UBound(fname)
    workbooks.Open Filename:=fname(i)
    wkbNameList = wkbNameList & workbooks(i + 1).Name & vbCrLf
    wkbNamePath = wkbNamePath & fname(i) & " , "
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function returns an array when files are selected, but returns a string when cancel/quit is selected

try this

```
Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, iCheck As Long
    Dim fname As Variant

    Dim wkbNameList As String, wkbNamePath As String
    Dim win As Window

    fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel, *xlsx; *xlsm", MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsArray(fname) Then 'file selected
        For i = LBound(fname) To UBound(fname)
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=fname(i)
            wkbNameList = wkbNameList & Workbooks(i + 1).Name & vbCrLf
            wkbNamePath = wkbNamePath & fname(i) & " , "
        Next i
    ElseIf fname = "False" Then 'cancel/quit
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The function returns a Variant. 1) String if a selection was made and MultiSelect is false, 2) Array if MultiSelect is true 3) Boolean if the user pressed cancel.

Comment: @Kostas did you check ? This is not my findings.

Comment: MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-getopenfilename-method-excel

Comment: @Kostas I could not find the confirmation for 1) and 3).

Comment: This method returns the selected file name or the name entered by the user (String). If MultiSelect is True, the return value is an array of the selected file names (even if only one filename is selected) (Array). Returns False if the user cancels the dialog box (Boolean).

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out by Kostas K. in the comments on h2so4's reply, the method returns boolean (False) when the dialog is cancelled, and array when a file is chosen.

I'd suggest trying this slight modification of h2so4's code:

```
Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long, j As Long, iCheck As Long
Dim fname() As Variant

Dim wkbNameList As String, wkbNamePath As String
Dim win As Window

fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel, *xlsx; *xlsm", MultiSelect:=True)

'the only option to get boolean is to have cancelled the dialog, which gives False for the variable
If VarType(fname) = vbBoolean Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    For i = LBound(fname) To UBound(fname)
        workbooks.Open Filename:=fname(i)
        wkbNameList = wkbNameList & workbooks(i + 1).Name & vbCrLf
        wkbNamePath = wkbNamePath & fname(i) & " , "
    Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

'I ran into this problem working with multiselect as well

'Something like this will work

'The problem is [cancel] returns a Boolean instead of an array.. so we make it return an array

```
Dim fname(), fname_catcherror() As Variant

fname_catcherror = Array(Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel, *xlsx; *xlsm", MultiSelect:=True), True)

if VarType(fname_catcherror(0)) <> vbBoolean Then


    fname = fname_catcherror(0)


    '..code here


end if
```

Comment: The `fname_catcherror` array serves no purpose.